# Cache usage under memory usage in System Monitor

Tags: 18.04, memory-usage, system-monitor

I came across Cache usage being shown under usual Memory usage section in System Monitor. It was never shown anytime earlier before today.

Here's an [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8GI0.png)

I'm curious to know what it means as using `htop` shows only Memory usage only and this is something new I've come across.

Comment: This happened to me as well.. Does anyone know what this means..?

Comment: @Ramesh-X, I've added an answer. Check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> cache is where linux uses some of your RAM to keep a cache of data recently read from the disk.
>
> Whenever a process wants more memory, cache is given to it as readily as free. free is the money you spent on RAM being utterly useless, cache is Linux making some use of it (so long as nothing else wants it).

as stated in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/310514/753984) answer.